# React Router refreshes URL but not the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some dynamically created Links and Routes (React Router) with path be like /details/{id} (using useParams)

When I click that link from '/' path everything works ok, but when I click it from another dynamically generated route (/details/{id}), it's just updating URL (specifically ID}, not the page's content

If I set force refresh prop on the BrowserRouter or just manually refresh the page, everything begins to work ok, but I don't want to refresh the whole page every time.

```
const App = () => {
    return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
          <Route path='/' exact>
            <FirstComponent id={id}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path={`/details/:id`}>
            <SecondComponent anotherId={anotherId}/>
          </Route>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

const FirstComponent = ({id}) => {
    return <Link to=`/details/${id}`></Link> //renders SecondComponent
}



const SecondComponent = ({anotherId}) => {
    const {id} = useParams()
  //does something with id
    return <Link to=`/details/${anotherId}`></Link> //Should render SecondComponent with another id but it doesn't

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code it is impossible to answer.

Comment: added code structure

Comment: Where does `FirstComponent` get the `id`  from?

Comment: From the body of an App component (forgot to write it here)

Comment: Where does `SecondComponent` get `anotherId` from?

Comment: From the body or from the server, this is not the point

Comment: It is not reproducible without a proper coherent and consistent minimal example.

Comment: Code you provider works as expected, https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-microservice-motbi?file=/src/App.js